# React - why am I getting "Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop" error if I HAVE a key (index)?

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about keys in an iteration with react. I understand they have o be unique and I picked it to be the index as I don't have an id in my data anyways. I keep getting the error:

Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

I included a part of my data array, perhaps it has something to do with the data? Any ideas would be great as I don't understand the reason for the error as I have a key. Thank you!!

my data:

```
[{
DestinationLocation :["AMS", "BCN", "BOS", "BRU", "LAS", "LAX", …],
OriginLocation: ["JFK", "LGA", "EWR"],
currency: ["USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", ...",
...
}]

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const flights = this.props.flightData.map((flight, i) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li key={i}>Flight leaves from: {flight.OriginLocation}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div>
            {flights}
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Move `key={i}` to the `<div`>.

Comment: The top level component returned from `map` should have the `key` prop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key property needs to be on the outer most element.  Move `key` from the `li` tag to the `div`.  The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) explain further.

```
const flights = this.props.flightData.map((flight, i) => {
    return (
        <div key={i}>
            <ul>
                <li>Flight leaves from: {flight.OriginLocation}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! could you explain why the key has to go to div and cannot be insight li or ul element? Thanks!

Comment: React uses keys to identify which items have changed, are added, or removed.  Without a `key` attribute on the `div`, React wouldn't be able to identify each `div` element.  If each `div` is identifiable, then it follows that each child element will also be (in this case the `ul` and `li` elements).  You can read about [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) if you want to learn about this in more depth.